# Passing a Map object into a constructor with optional parameters?

Tags: dart

I have a Map with a 1:1 ratio on the optional constructor parameters for my class.  The issue is that I can't do:  `test = new Foo(myMap);`.

Is there a way to explode it out, or should I change it around such that it accepts a Map and then loop over the Map?

I was hoping I could do it by exploding the Map's key-value pairs but I don't think that is likely.

I remember a previous post discussing just accepting the Map and then parsing it inside the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plans to support deconstruction but this might not even be planned for maps.

I would make the parameter of type map and then do the assignment in the constructor body, or if you want final fields then in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: I agree. I'd probably have two constructors: one with normal parameters (and some perhaps named) and one `.fromMap(Map parameters)`. The latter could delegate to the former: `Foo.fromMap(map): this(map["a"], ... , baz: map["baz"]);`